# How to fit console output in pdf generated by Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

[image][image]

I am trying to print `str(df)` in pdf output of rmarkdown. How do I fit the wide output in pdf?

Comment: There is a console width option. See “?options”

Comment: Please include representative code in the question.

Comment: @peter I have included the code in the question and tried different ways to fit the output but nothing works

Comment: @Sana You posted an answer below which was deleted by @Dharman, who has never answered a single `r` or `knitr` question on SO (hence I question how @Dharman is qualified to do so). I don't know why it was deleted, but it is a totally legitimate answer (could be improved but definitely should not be deleted). Basically you mentioned the example at https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/077-wrap-output.Rmd, and I'm pasting the link here again.

Comment: @YihuiXie thanks, the solution in that link works for me so I thought of sharing the link. Thanks for sharing the link again which may helps to improve the solution

Answer (score 1):

For PDF output is a bit trickier to wrap lines. One option is using the LaTeX package `listings`. I will use `mtcars` dataset as example. Your Rmarkdown should enable the package via the Pandoc argument `--listings` like this:

````
---
title: "Test"
output:
  pdf_document:
    pandoc_args: --listings
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
options(width = 300)
str(mtcars)
```
````

In `preamble.tex`, you set an option of the package in a different file:

```
\lstset{
  breaklines=true
  basicstyle=\ttfamily
}
```

This is the output:

[image]

For more info check this link: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/text-width.html

Comment: I tried this  although it wrap the text to next row and fit the output in pdf but it removes other code chunk display format in pdf as well